# Difference using lists

Tags: list, insertion-sort

Which is the difference of the structure of the insertion sort using arrays and using linked lists.

To implement the insertion sorst for lists  do we use the algorithm for arrays and just change the commands A(k)=A(k+1) ?

Are there more differences?

Answer (score 1):

There is *no* other difference.

The array elements are accessed by incrementing the index, whereas the list elements will be accessed by traversing to the next node. Based on the programming language, the syntax might vary.

Comment: Is the only difference at the while loop where we traverse the list and check if the elements are greater than the key element?

Comment: Yes, and that too is syntactical difference only, as you have a different syntax to access a list element and an array element.